# Next 13 fetch & caching best practice on your own api

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js

What's the best practice for fetching & caching data from my own api in the latest NextJS 13.4+ env? Let's assume I'm doing this all SSR.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/caching

These docs propose two approaches. One is to use `fetch()` which automatically cache's and deduplicates the request, and the other is to use React's built in `cache()` wrapper that memoize's the result & dedupes in a similar way.

In my case, it's unclear to me which one I should be using since I'm calling my own API route for fetching data. My endpoint's just call and return data from some service functions:

**/api/user?id=${id}**

```
import { getUser } from '@/services/user';

export async function GET (request: Request) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
    const id = searchParams.get('id');
    const user = await getUser(id);
    return NextResponse.json({user});
}
```

**services/user**

```
export const getUser = async (id: string) => {
    const user = <database logic here>
    return user;
};
```

The reason I'm confused is because it seems inefficient to me to be making a fetch request on my own API. Wouldn't that spawn an unnecessary new request on my server? So then, should I just be calling `getUser()` directly and wrapping the function in `cache` like so?

**services/user**

```
import 'server-only';
import { cache } from 'react';

export const getUser = cache(async (id: string) => {
    const user = <database logic here>
    return user;
});
```

Approach 1 in practice, with `fetch()`

**Page.tsx**

```
async function getUserData(id:string) {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST}/api/user?id=${id}`);

    if ( !res.ok ) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch user data');
    }

    const data = await res.json();
    return data.user;
}
```

Approach 2 in practice, with `cache()`

**Page.tsx**

```
async function getUserData(id:string) {
    const user = await getUser(id);

    if ( !user ) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch user data');
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT's take. https://chat.openai.com/share/54ce55aa-8cb6-423e-bee1-d5408e1eec35